# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') from document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I wish to read the value of this input field.

```
<input type="text" name="acadp_fields[1200]" class="text" placeholder="" value="December 26, 1969">
```

My code is this.

```
document.getElementById("acadp-upload-file-ipfs").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    document.getElementById("acadp-upload-file-ipfs").removeAttribute("href");

    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '<div class="acadp-spinner"></div>';

    const dateOfBirth = document.getElementById('acadp_fields[1200]').value;

    ...
    ...
```

But I'm getting the error below when I click the element `acadp-upload-file-ipfs`

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no element with the ID `acadp_fields[1200]`. Did you mean `document.getElementsByName("acadp_fields[1200]")[0]` or `document.querySelector("[name='acadp_fields[1200]']")`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Sorry, I'm new to this. How should I actually read '<input type="text" name="acadp_fields[1200]" class="text" placeholder="" value="December 26, 1969">'? Should `document.querySelector` be the best way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

document.getElementsByName("acadp_fields[1200]")[0].value